# Auto switch sound sink on power change

Tags: macos, automator, automation, power-management, sound-volume

I like to switch various working positions at home. I want to make it change to the bluetooth speakers on power plugged in. And switch to internal speakers when unplugged. How to do it with some App or programming API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a python script that calls SwitchAudioSource installed by `brew install switchaudio-osx`:

```py
import psutil
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    if psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged:
        subprocess.run(["SwitchAudioSource", "-s", "EDIFIER S301"])
    else:
        subprocess.run(["SwitchAudioSource", "-s", "MacBook Pro扬声器"])
    time.sleep(10)
```